# How to manage multiple IoT Agents in Fiware

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion

I have two type of devices one support IoT JSON agent and another Ultralight Iot Agent. What approach is best should i used both IoT agent separately or there is something like IoT manager. What in future i have another device which support another IoT Agent like LoRaWan .

I have tried IoT manager but could not understand it is only for device provisioning or actual device data transfer also.

Comment: Do you refere to the IOTA Manager at https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-manager ?

Comment: Yes. I do refer to this link. But my doubt remains that do i really need IoT Manager or I can do without it.

Answer (score 1):

IoT Manager acts as a proxy for actual IOTAs, so depending on some parameters in the request (I don't remember exactly which ones, but they should be described in the IOTAs documentation) redirects the request to one or another IOTA agent.

But of course, you can implement this proxy using another piece of software (e.g. ngix with some king of URL-based or port-based redirection) if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. IoT manager is not doing anything special , if i will not use IoT Manager and still can use different IoT agents in my application. IoT manager is not managing IoT agents it is just enabling device or configuration provisioning that can be easily done without IoT manager.  Or there is any scenario i am missing or would not able to implement without IoT Manager?

Comment: What IOTA Manager does is to provide a single API endpoint for all the IOTAs, dispatching request to the right IOTA depending on the request itself. If that is "special" or no it's a matter of opinion of course ;)